# Self made microphone burns arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, soldering, microphone

I'm very new to electrical engineering and I'm trying to read microphone input with arduino nano. I've made a separate microphone module ([based on this example](https://engmousaalkaabi.blogspot.lt/2015/10/sound-level-detector-using-arduino-and.html)) and plugged it into aruino like this:

[image: Connection]
Unfortunately it was the last time my arduino was working. It's no longer displayed as a connection, and acts "randomly", so I think my microphone toasts controller for some reason. Here are some more pictures and a scheme of my mic module, could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjjtVH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**R1** - CR1/4W 10 (brown,black,black,gold)

**R2** - CR1/4W 2KO (red,black,red,gold)

*I have no education in electrical engineering, so I'm not sure about the corectness of this schema of units, just pasted what's written on the pack*

[image: Back]
[image: Front]

Comment: The resistor is 10 Ohm. Not KOhm... If I read the color code correctly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There's one brown and one red

Comment: Unless I'm completely blind, or you have messed with the colors, that's Brown, Black, Black = 1 0 0 = 10 ohm.

Comment: Huh? I see a resistor brown-black-black. Which is \$10\Omega\$

Comment: How is the Arduino powered?

Comment: 2k is red-black-red. 10k is brown-back-orange. So the resistors look wrong. On the solder side of the veroboard, two of the wires on the left edge look like their is a solder bridge between the two tracks. Have you go a multimeter to measure the resistance between tracks? Test the Arduino by disconnecting the microphone, loading blink, and if that works test the other pins with a simple arduino sketch and a potentiometer or resistors as voltage divers. even if you've damaged A0, other Ain pins might still work.

Comment: @gbulmer there's no solder bridge. I've corrected the resistors on the schema.

Comment: @pipe powered via usb

Comment: @Benedictus The problem is not with the schematic, it is that the value of R1 in your physical circuit is 1000 times lower than what is indicated on the schematic. If you bought this as a kit, it is possible that they shipped the wrong component, or perhaps they shipped several different component and you accidentally mixed them up.

Comment: @pipe the brown resistor worked fine in different schema. It says CR1/4W 10 on the package for the brown one, and CR1/4W 2K0 for the red one. I bought them myself in batches.

Comment: @Benedictus 10 ohm is not 10 *kilo*ohm. It's off by a factor of one thousand. The schematic clearly shows `10 K`. The color code for that would be Brown, Black, Orange. Maybe the other schema needed a 10 ohm resistor.

Comment: @pipe dont trust the schema I've painted - I'm not good at that. Look at this info instead:
R1 - CR1/4W 10 (brown,black,black,gold)

R2 - CR1/4W 2KO (red,black,red,gold)

and example I used https://engmousaalkaabi.blogspot.lt/2015/10/sound-level-detector-using-arduino-and.html

Comment: That also shows `10k`, not `10`.

Comment: @pipe ok, that's besides the point because I've already said I'm bad at schemas and provided detailed info. What I'm after is why it burns my chips?

Comment: When you put wrong components instead of the right ones, it has a good probability to burn something. How can we tell you haven't done anything else not as per "schema"?

Answer (score 3):

I did this a very long time ago, so I might forget something. However, I'm almost completely sure I used resistors in the Kohm range.

After googling a bit I found this [post](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/microphone_powering.html), which might help you get a better understanding of how to use your microhpone.

However, I have noticed you intend to connect your microphone to the analog input of an Arduino. So remember to polarize the analog output to around 2.5V (maybe employing an Operational AMplifier to avoid distortion?) in order to avoid loosing part of your signal (if it is too close to 0V or 5V).

---

I have checked [the circuit you provided](https://engmousaalkaabi.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/sound-level-detector-using-arduino-and.html). Indeed, it uses 10Kohm and 4.7Kohm to polarize the microphone.

That is, your Arduino gets fried because the 10ohm resistor draws relatively high currents (in the order of 500mA) which Arduino is not designed to handle.

I'm sure that once you replace your resistor your circuit will work fine :) Good luck!

Comment: what resistors should i use?

Comment: @Benedictus You need to use a 10 kΩ resistor for R1 and a 4.7 kΩ resistor for R2. The "k" stands for "times 1000", so they are 10,000 Ω and 4700 Ω respectively. If you're going to be doing a bit of this sort of stuff, you can get bags of a variety of resistors from eBay and the like. They may not be of the highest quality, but if you give them a quick check with a multimeter on its resistance setting to check the value (until you can read resistor colour codes straight off) they will be OK.

Comment: An Arduino should be nominally able to withstand a short to ground or digital supply on any of its output pins, the pin drivers are effectively current sources limited to a couple tens of mA. It'll be overstressing the chip but shouldn't permanently damage it: been there and done that many times. The connections as shown in the question are useless, but shouldn't damage an Arduino as long as it is a model that accepts 5V inputs.

Comment: @kuba thank you, I was not aware that the Arduino board could whithstand shortcuts :) Although now that I think about it, it does make sense, given that it is usually used for training.

Comment: @andresgongora I should add that the "Arduino" part of it is not very relevant, it's a basic property of most CMOS microcontrollers. An Arduino typically doesn't buffer any GPIO signals: Arduino I/O pins are Atmel chip's I/O pins :)